# XML Customized transformation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have input XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Vehicle>
<Ordinary>
    <Car>Honda City</Car>
</Ordinary> 
<Luxury>
    <Car>Volkswagon</Car>
</Luxury>   
<Luxury>
    <Car>Dzire</Car>
</Luxury>
```

I have to transform this xml message using XSLT into,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item>
<id>1</id>
<title>/Vehicle/Ordinary/</title>
<text>Car</text>
<answer>Honda City</answer>
</item>
<item>
<id>2</id>
<title>/Vehicle/Luxury[1]/</title>
<text>Car</text>
<answer>Volkswagon</answer>
</item>
<item>
<id>3</id>
<title>/Vehicle/Luxury[2]/</title>
<text>Car</text>
<answer>Dzire</answer>
</item>
```

- Here id could be autogenerated unique number..
- All the parent tags Xpath who does not any value will come inside <title> tag.
- The element which is having value come inside <text> tag.
- The actual value come inside <answer> tag.
- The XSLT should be generic enough to apply any format of XML document & not specific to the given sample xml.

I have started with below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements = "*" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<items>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</items>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
<item>      
<title>
<xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="name()" />
</xsl:for-each>
</title>    
<answer>
<xsl:value-of select="." />
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</answer>
</item>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It generates below output,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item>
<id>1</id>
<title>/Vehicle/Ordinary/Car</title>
<answer>Honda City</answer>
</item>
<item>
<id>2</id>
<title>/Vehicle/Luxury[1]/Car</title>   
<answer>Volkswagon</answer>
</item>
<item>
<id>2</id>
<title>/Vehicle/Luxury[2]/Car</title>   
<answer>Dzire</answer>
</item>
</items>
```

Need your help...

Comment: You've given us the requirements, but you haven't shown us what you've tried or where you're having problems. There's no actual question. It seems more like a ["Do you haz teh codez?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/13235) request.

Comment: @Daniel : Added the XSLT which I have used to start the transformation

Comment: "*The XSLT should be generic enough to apply any format of XML document*" There is no such thing. XML is very flexible, and one XSLT cannot possibly process any XML schema - unless the processing is utterly meaningless (e.g. the identity transform).

Answer (score 0):

> Here id could be autogenerated unique number..

I'd use `generate-id()` to get a unique id.

> All the parent tags Xpath who does not any value will come inside
>   `<title>` tag.

Based on your target output, it looks like you want the ancestors except for the first one.

> The element which is having value come inside `<text>` tag.

Just use the `name()` of the parent.

> The actual value come inside `<answer>` tag.

Looks like you've got that covered.

Example...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements= "*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <items>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </items>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <item>
      <id><xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/></id>
      <title>
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*[position()>1]">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>
          <xsl:if test="(preceding-sibling::*|
            following-sibling::*)[name()=name(current())]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',
              count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])+1,
              ']')"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
      </title>
      <text><xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/></text>
      <answer>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </answer>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<items>
   <item>
      <id>d0t4</id>
      <title>/Vehicle/Ordinary/</title>
      <text>Car</text>
      <answer>Honda City</answer>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>d0t7</id>
      <title>/Vehicle/Luxury[1]/</title>
      <text>Car</text>
      <answer>Volkswagon</answer>
   </item>
   <item>
      <id>d0t10</id>
      <title>/Vehicle/Luxury[2]/</title>
      <text>Car</text>
      <answer>Dzire</answer>
   </item>
</items>
```

Comment: The OP mentions wanting `<id>` to be a unique, auto-generated _number_; `generate-id()` doesn't guarantee this (as your output demonstrates). One possibility is to count the preceding vehicle nodes: `<id><xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/></id>`

Comment: @ABach - True, it isn't guaranteed to be a number, but it is guaranteed to be unique which counting preceding siblings does not guarantee.

Comment: Is there any way to generate Unique Ordered Sequence Number for id?

I don't want any character for id.

Comment: @MaheshB - I would replace `<xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>` with `<xsl:number level="any"/>`.

Comment: @Daniel - The above solution does not creates index at <text> level.  Consider the xml,<Vehicle>
 <Car>Volkswagon</Car>
 <Car>Dzire</Car>
 <Car>Honda City</Car>
</Vehicle>

Comment: @MaheshB - I don't know what you mean by _"does not creates index at <text> level"_. It seems to work for me: http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zCq

Comment: @Daniel - So here Vehicle contains List of Cars. Hence it should be  <text>Car[1]</text>.... <text>Car[2]</text>... <text>Car[3]</text>

One more point if my List/Array contains only one element, it won't populate then indexes.  I mean, there has to be some logic which tells us about where to populate indexes for the nodes.